# Yarn adds npm but npm shows wrong version

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Windows 10 powershell:

```
> yarn global add npm@4.6.1  
> npm --version  
> 3.10.10
```

When I check yarn

```
> yarn npm --version  
> $ C:\WINDOWS\system32\node_modules\.bin\npm --version  
> 4.6.1
```

I have flushed caches etc...  I need to use both yarn and npm and they should be in sync.  Any ideas on what to check?

```
> npm cache clean --force
> npm uninstall npm -g
> npm --version 
> 3.10.10
```

I have also deleted npm folders and files,  still cant remove npm.  I am using node 6...

Comment: You likely have another version of npm on your path somewhere. If you are using Windows, run the command `where npm` from command prompt and post the output.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32> where npm  (returns nothing)

Comment: I rebooted windows and now >npm -- version 4.61    (which is now correct)